# RegExp returns unexpected result

Tags: javascript, regex

I am playing with regular expressions in Javascript and have stumbled across an unexpected behaviour. Take a look: https://jsfiddle.net/ft7h5cw0/

I am trying to replace `.html-wrap` string in a `#my-html-wrapper-random .html-wrap .main-content` with `#my-html-wrapper-random .html-wrap`. For some reason, the result after replacement is:

`#my#my-html-wrapper-randomper-random .html-wrap .main-content` instead of expeceted `#my-html-wrapper-random #my-html-wrapper-random .main-content`

What is the reason for this behaviour?

```js
var testString = "#my-html-wrapper-random .html-wrap .main-content";
var rxString = ".html-wrap";
var rx = new RegExp(rxString);
var result = testString.replace(rx,"#my-html-wrapper-random"); // unexpexted result strinf
console.log(result);
```

Comment: As Wiktor pointed out, this is a simple mistake. One that you would have spotted if you used a regex tool like [Regex101](https://regex101.com/). In regular expressions, the period means "any character".

Comment: The result is as expected. `.` matches any char but a line break char. Actually, I see no point using this regex, use `var result = testString.replace(".html-wrap", "#my-html-wrapper-random")`. To replace case insensitively and all occurrences, use `var result = testString.replace(new RegExp(rxString.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&'), 'gi'), "#my-html-wrapper-random")`

Comment: thanks. For some reason I thought RegExp would handle this by default. stupid me